# Не отображаются изменения в файле Git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

Есть проект на C# и в нём класс Program, все файлы были добавлены в Git при помощи git add .
Но почему то когда я делаю изменения в самом файле Program.cs при использовании команды git status гит меня не оповещает об изменение в этом файле, а всё так же показывает, что файлы добавлены в git. Код пишется при помощи Visual Studio
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Гит работает по принципу "контрольных точек", где вы каждое изменение должны зафиксировать, после чего уже будет отслеживать изменения, сверяя файл с последней версией файла в гит.

Comment: после git add нужно делать git commit

Comment: Для Visual Studio есть расширение для гита, студия в человечесеом формате может показывать и статус, и коммиты делать и ветку пушить в репозитоний.

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но всё же: не следует добавлять в гит временные файлы и результаты сборки. Посмотрите как работает gitignore!

Answer (score 1):

Команда `git add` помещает все изменения, которые вы сделали в индекс, другими словами подготавливает будущий коммит. На этом этапе ещё сохраняется возможность изменить будущий коммит (добавить в него новые изменения, разделить сделанные изменения на два коммита, полностью откатить изменения). Эти подготовленные изменения ещё не зафиксированы. Для того, чтобы из зафиксировать необходимо вызвать команду `git commit`. Только после этого будет создан и сохранён в истории сам коммит - неизменяемый снимок состояния ваших файлов.

Команда `git status` позволяет посмотреть в каком из состояний находятся ваши файлы. В данном случае, поскольку все файлы были подготовлены для коммита, они отмечены как `new file`.